# What is causing this line to be repeatedly drawn in Angular/D3.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I'm using this great tutorial to learn how to use the D3.js library with AngularJS: http://briantford.com/blog/angular-d3. The tutorial works as provided (thanks Brian!)

But I'm trying to learn/understand this code so that I can hack it up and draw what I want. I have simply added the following block of code before the line containing `var bars = layers.selectAll("g.bar")`:

```
    console.log('Setup');
    var grid = layers.selectAll("g.grid")
        .data(function(d) { return d; })
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "grid")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
          console.log("1");
          return "translate(" + x(d) + ",0)";
        });

    console.log('About to draw a line');
    grid.append("line")          // attach a line
      .style("stroke", "green")  // colour the line
      .attr("x1", 100)     // x position of the first end of the line
      .attr("y1", 50)      // y position of the first end of the line
      .attr("x2", 300)     // x position of the second end of the line
      .attr("y2", 150);
```

I expected this to draw a single diagonal green line. Instead it draws 700+ diagonal green lines (see screenshot below). Why? I don't see any `for` or `while` loop that would cause this. So why is it happening? I inserted the console.log lines above. It printed `About to draw line` once. But it printed `1` 702 times. Why? Here is the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zEicBc2Q0B6TsWv0wD66?p=preview)

[image]

Comment: On line `181` you're appending a line on grid which is a huge array of stuff, thus it's appending the line on each of the grid elements.. You should append the bar only on the element you want :)

Comment: I don't know where you want to append it, but if you append it on the `layers` var you obtain a single line https://plnkr.co/edit/IYRuHptmpf08GTa8t03s?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line :

```
grid.append("line")
```

appends a line to the grid, meaning you are using the same data from grid. And as your grid is like so :

```
var grid = layers.selectAll("g.grid")
        .data(function(d) { return d; })
```

It is using the same data from layers :

```
var layers = vis.selectAll("g.layer")
            .data(data)
```

So, this data is of length 18, but each one has an array of 39 elements, thus `18x39=702` i.e the amount of lines you have.

Basically you want to append the line to `vis` instead of grid, otherwise you will use the same data.

```
vis.append("line")          // attach a line
          .style("stroke", "green")  // colour the line
          .attr("x1", 100)     // x position of the first end of the line
          .attr("y1", 50)      // y position of the first end of the line
          .attr("x2", 300)     // x position of the second end of the line
          .attr("y2", 150);
```

Updated Plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/MTQ9pNWL2784jPfRWH5F?p=preview

Comment: Follow-up question: At the point when I'm drawing the line, how can I find the width and height of the canvas?

Comment: The canvas being the svg ?

Comment: Give it an id : svg.attr('id','svgContainer); then get the width by javascript : document.getElementById('svgContainer').width; ? That what you want ?

Comment: Hmm. Not quite right. I added the attribute and then inserted this: `console.log('About to draw a line. SVG width = ', document.getElementById('svgContainer').width);`. That yields this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1UFylbhbG2eVHhHYlZkTFhRcVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: My bad, I'm confusing JQuery with JS, instead of width, put clientWidth or offsetWidth :) offsetWidth includes border width, clientWidth does not.